# When patching SQL FCI, how to ensure there will not be a failover to the node being patched?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, clustering, patching

This is about patching a 2 node SQL FCI.

Say node1 is the current active node.

When I am patching the node2, how do I ensure that there won't be a automatic failover to node2 even if node1 crashes during patching?

Answer (score 4):

The [correct and documented procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver16#RollOwnership) is to use the `/FAILOVERCLUSTERROLLOWNERSHIP` parameter when calling the upgrade source.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/upgrade-a-sql-server-failover-cluster-instance?view=sql-server-ver16#perform-a-rolling-upgrade-or-update says that `As you upgrade each node, it is left out of the possible owners of the failover cluster instance. If there is an unexpected failover, the upgraded nodes do not participate in the failover until Windows Server failover cluster role ownership is moved to an upgraded node by setup.`. I had thought this was auto decided by the patching process but looks to be manual option.

Comment: literally the next sentence is, "By default, SQL Server setup automatically determines when to fail over to an upgraded node." and then goes into the parameter I specified in my answer. I'm unsure as to what the confusion is or why items are taken out of context.

Comment: It's unclear to me whether I need to manually specify this parameter `FAILOVERCLUSTERROLLOWNERSHIP`

Comment: If you read the link to the documentation I gave you, you'd find this is explained, "`/FAILOVERCLUSTERROLLOWNERSHIP=2` is the default setting. It will be used if this parameter isn't specified. "

Comment: It says the =2 is default and that `This setting indicates that SQL Server Setup will manage cluster ownership (move group) as needed.` - where can I find what `as needed` means? I'm looking for something that will conclusively tell me that - by default, node 1 will never fail over to node 2 during the ongoing patching of node 2.

Comment: It's literally in the _same_ document that I've now asked you to read _3 different times_.

Comment: I can't find the explanation of `as needed`, please be so kind to show me where I can find this.

Comment: What does setup will manage ownership as needed actually mean?

Comment: @variable You have all the information available at the same link I've given 3 times. I can't force you to read and digest the data, nor will I continue to post the same link (which you've directly quoted) again. I've given you the answer, I'm not here to write your dissertation on the subject.